# Restrict access to some url via web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, https, web-config

I would like to know if there is a way for to setup my **Web.config** file in order to grant access to some of my urls only to http requests coming with a valid username and password in the request header.

Answer (score 0):

You should see [Identity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/security/?view=aspnetcore-3.1). That way you can add a login system to your service, and using decorators such as `[Authorize]` you can restrict access to some endpoints only to authenticated users